# aggregating for stacked bar chart

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I want to display data on a stacked bar chart.

The bins will be category "A", "B", "C".

Each bar will be broken into the counts for Active(1) or notActive (0), and show the counts.

Im really struggling with it. Ive gotten close with ggplot but would appreciate some examples to help
me see where im going wrong.

```
isActive <- c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0)
category <- c('A','B','A','C','C','B','B','C','A')
df <- data.frame(category, isActive)

df
category isActive
1        A        1
2        B        0
3        A        1
4        C        1
5        C        0
6        B        1
7        B        1
8        C        1
9        A        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(category), fill = factor(isActive))) 

g + geom_bar() # Stacked
g + geom_bar(position = "dodge") # Side-by-side
```

We can also show the counts using `geom_text`. For example:

```
g + geom_bar(position = "dodge")  +  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..),  position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

These plots are also fairly quick to do with base graphics:

```
barplot(with(df, table(isActive, category)))
barplot(with(df, table(isActive, category)), beside = TRUE)
```

Comment: that has helped a lot, thanks! i was making a mountain out of it, as every example i could find on google using ggplot was much more complicated.